# Unable to install steam on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, steam

I've just installed Ubuntu on my chromebook because I want a little more functionality (<3 the design, not much utility on chrome os besides crosh)

I used sudo apt-get to get the steam-launcher package, which then installs. When I try to run it, steam says that it needs to install some missing packages (libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 and libc6:i386)

I give it my password, but it returns errors saying that it is unable to locate the packages.

I've tried using sudo apt-get to find each of the packages to no avail. In the terminal, I am told that "steam is missing the following libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6

I have also tried using sudo apt-get to download this package, to no effect. (unable to find package)

I have also used sudo apt-get update, then reinstalled steam.

I should also mention I've been using ubuntu for all of 3 hours, so bear with me here if I'm making a stupid mistake or if there's an obvious fix.

Comment: What ubuntu version are you using??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing it from the steam.com website? That worked for me on ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

You can use Synaptic Package Manager to resolve package dependencies.